# Why does a maven plugin work even if it's only defined in the pluginManagement section of the parent POM?

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

If I define a parent POM like this:

```
<project ...>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
</project>
```

And a project POM like this:

```
<project ...>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent-test-project</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent-test</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
</project>
```

The goal `spring-boot:help`, among others, are available from the `parent-test-project` root directory.  Why doesn't the plugin need to be included in a `<plugins>` block in the project to use the plugin?  Even the [spring docs suggest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-maven-plugin) that this should be necessary.

Same result with another plugin:  https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Maven2+Plugin+Installation.html

Related, but seems different since I'm asking about running a goal directly, as opposed to binding to a lifecycle phase:  ["Implicit" plugins - why does a Maven build run tests via surefire even if it is not mentioned in the POM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9362285/implicit-plugins-why-does-a-maven-build-run-tests-via-surefire-even-if-it-is)

Comment: Please post the full pom files here...

Comment: Those are the full POM files.

Comment: Simply wrong, cause at least the modelVersion is not part of it so it will fail already a simple `mvn clean` ...best would be to make an full example project on github where you observe the problems...

Comment: They are slightly edited for readability. Sheesh.

Comment: @jordanpg were you able to find anything? I have a similar question.